# Blackberry Android Native Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am currently looking into porting some of my Android Live Wallpapers to Blackberry. Is this possible?

I can't seem to find any info about whether or not Blackberry devices support Nartive Android Live Wallpapers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On initial release RIM stated that Live Wallpaper would not be supported, and I haven't seen anything to the contrary. Other features available on an actual Android device such as Java Native Interface are also unlikely to ever be supported. Remember that the BlackBerry Android run time environment is meant to allow Android Java applications to run. You might think of the BlackBerry run time as providing a Dalvik VM (though I don't think that is technically accurate). Each Android application runs in its own copy of the run-time environment. It does not provide the entire Android OS as a guest OS like VMWare, VirtualBox or QEMU would.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it will ever support Android Live Wallpapers. Every ported Android app runs in special runtime isolated from rest of BB OS.

On my opinion Android ports are just temporary solution that RIM chosen to bridge the gap when not enough native apps.

Cascades/QML is awesome framework so I'm almost sure that Android apps will be very quickly replaced with native equivalents.